# AMD Radeon HD 5650M

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

Ok, so I've got the 5650 as a discrete gpu and integrated 4200. The problem is that I cant switch to 5650.
fglrxinfo shows that 4200 is on, but aticonfig -px-list shows that Discrete GPU is active.

lspci shows this:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc M880G [Mobility Radeon HD 4200] [1002:9712]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc Madison [AMD Radeon HD 5000M Series] [1002:68c1] (rev ff)
```

as xorg looks like this:

```
xorg device section:

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
   Driver      "fglrx"
   BusID       "PCI:1:5:0"
EndSection
```

I thought that if I change busid to PCI:2:0:0 it'll help, but it won't.
looks like ubuntu can't see 5650 as with PCI:2:0:0 I cant run X.
any suggestions what to do?

Also I can't disable 4200 in BIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried switching with `vgaswitcheroo`? For more information on this topic, have a look at [HybridGraphics in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).
When it comes to owning `vgaswitcheroo`, I use:

`sudo chmod -R 705 /sys/kernel/debug` and

`sudo chown -R $YOURUSERNAME:$YOURUSERNAME /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo`

I don't use the proprietary drivers though.

Comment: SOLVED
I simply uninstal fglxr, and then I did everything from this site:
http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com/