# How to disable ATI 6490m and only use Intel HD

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a Probook 4530s and just installed Ubuntu a week ago. This laptop has both an ATI 6490m graphics chipset and integrated Intel HD graphics.

The ATI graphics seem to overheat the system, resulting in freezes. How can I disable the ATI and use the integrated Intel HD 3000 instead?

I don't need the ATI in for Ubuntu, just for gaming in Windows 7. BIOS is no option because I don't want to enable and disable the graphic all the time I'm switching between Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to permanently switch off discrete graphic card?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89205/how-to-permanently-switch-off-discrete-graphic-card)

Answer (score 0):

uninstall `fglrx` if you have installed it and then follow [this answer on hybrid graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99685)

The overheating problem you are facing is most probably coming from the default that both graphic cards are running. Turn one of and the overheating should be history.

Comment: what about the way of blacklisting the ATI gpu? i read about that, but didn't understand that right...

Comment: I think you have something in mind like `echo "blacklist radeon" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. This is something you do if you face problems with my posted solution. Also you then would have to add `modprobe radeon`
`echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` in `/etc/rc.local`. What this would do is deactivate the AMD ATI card. This is then done by not loading the `radeon` module and initialising it afterwards on boot. `vga_switcheroo` needs `radeon` to be enabled, therefore this extra step. It ensures that `radeon` is loaded second and will therefore be turned off.

Comment: after multiple system lacks, freezes, starts without unity, running on low graphics and other failures, this is what worked for me.
http://planetoss.com/articles/how-to-disable-the-discrete-amd-graphics-card-in-linux/

Comment: ok, just half an hour later... not that lucky anymore. recived multiple apport messages caused by hanging GPU...
Executable path:
/usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py

even the apport popups have graphicbugs, some of them appear without showing any thing, they just look like a Pill with a black top and a white bottom. any suggestions? maybe it could be the Intel driver :D, maybe...

Comment: have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/143102 also what GPU are you now running? Discrete or the Intel one?

Comment: Intel is running right now and producing these lacks, and graphicbugs... would an driver update solve this problem?

~$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0

Comment: I can't promise anything, but you could try `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`or even `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`. Just be sure that you know what you are doing. This is bleeding edge.

Comment: commands not found, tried it with sudo, same here...

Comment: these are user repositories. Obviously you don't know anything about it so I highly recommend reading on this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983 Essentially it breaks down to you adding them with `sudo add-apt-repository`. After that you - in this case - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Again I want to stress that you should not do that if you don't know what you are doing!